# Selenium Webdriver findelement i sendKeys() isn't behaving as expected

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to identify elements in Firefox using below xpath and name values in selenium webdriver but it is not working. [This is link to the web page which I want to automate](https://www.dpdpickup.pl/Wycen-i-nadaj-Online/nadaj-online/przesylka-krajowa;jsessionid=1c703751914a93ae5a7d604cd0ad.000000). All of the input fields on this page look weird to me and I don't understand how to fill them.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("sender-postCode")).sendKeys("02791");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='stepOneForm']/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("02791");
```

This is my code:

```
package SalesBar;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
public class Salesbar {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/User/Documents/SeleniumWebDriver/geckodriver.exe");
    ProfilesIni profil = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myprofile = profil.getProfile("default");

    WebDriver driver;
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);

    driver.get("https://wwwuat.dpdpickup.pl/Wycen-i-nadaj-Online");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='contentWrapper']/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='stepOneForm']/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]/label/span")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("parcels-1-weight")).sendKeys("5");
    }
```

Please let me know if there is a standard way in WebDriver to find and fill these fields.

Answer (score 1):

An issue with all test automation tools is that the page may not have finished loading the [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) when the automation tool executes.  There are various levels of sophistication that can be employed to get this to be 100% reliable.  The first line of defense is to use [ExpectedConditions](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).  So for your first example,

```
WebDriver webDrive = ... // You have to initialize to a browser instance and navigate to your web page
By bySenderPostCode = By.name("sender-postCode");
Wait<WebDriver> wait_element = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 40); // Wait up to 40 seconds
WebElement senderPostalCodeElement = wait_element.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(bySenderPostCode));
senderPostalCodeElement.sendKeys("02791");
```

Complex pages with lots of executing JavaScript can be a pain. I use routines that that I have written to wait for angularJs to complete executing, wait for a loading spinner to complete, and finally for page readyState to equal complete:

```
waitForAngularToLoad(webDriver, 40);
wait_element.until((WebDriver dr1) -> (webDriver.findElement(mySpinner).getAttribute("class").contains("ng-hide")));
waitForBrowserReadystateComplete(webDriver);
```

These have to be tweaked for the environment that you have to operate in.  Waiting for jQuery to complete is different than waiting for AngularJs. But what I gave you should get you going.  Let me know how it turns out.

**EDIT**

I realize that telling you about my routines that I use to wait but not sharing the code was pointless.  The loading spinner depends entirely on the implementation.  There is no one way that is guaranteed to work everywhere but I gave you the general form which is common for AngularJs implementations.

Here are the others:

```
public void waitForBrowserReadystateComplete(WebDriver webDriver) {
    for (int a=0; a<20; a++) {
        JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
        if (javascriptExecutor.executeScript("return document.readyState")
                .toString().equals("complete")) {
            break;
        }
        sleepResponsibly(500);
    }
}

public void sleepResponsibly(int timeMillisecond){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(timeMillisecond);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

public boolean waitForAngularToLoad(WebDriver driver, int timeout) {
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, 500L);
    return wait.until(angularHasFinishedProcessing());
}


public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> angularHasFinishedProcessing() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            String hasAngularFinishedScript = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];\n" +
                    "var el = document.querySelector('html');\n" +
                    "if (!window.angular) {\n" +
                    "    callback('false')\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "if (angular.getTestability) {\n" +
                    "    angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                    "} else {\n" +
                    "    if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {\n" +
                    "        callback('false')\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "    var browser = angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser');\n" +
                    "    browser.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                    "}";

            JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String isProcessingFinished = javascriptExecutor.executeAsyncScript(hasAngularFinishedScript).toString();

            return Boolean.valueOf(isProcessingFinished);
        }
    };
}
```

Remember, the angular ones only work if your System Under Test is built using AngularJs.

**EDIT 2** Finding elements

I use the google chrome browser to "find" elements.  Open your web page under chrome. Right-click on the displayed element. Select Inspect -> Copy -> Copy Selector | Copy Xpath.  You can do this under Firefox as well.  Chrome is just force of habit.

**EDIT3**

jQuery

```
public boolean waitForJquery(WebDriver driver, int timeout) {
    return waitFor(driver, "return jQuery.active;", "0", timeout);
}

public boolean waitFor(WebDriver driver, final String javascriptString, final String targetString, int timeout) {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, 500L);

  /*
   * If you are curious about what follows see:
\  *    http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html
   * 
   * We are creating an anonymous class that inherits from ExpectedCondition and then implements interface
   * method apply(...)
   */
   ExpectedCondition<Boolean> isLoaded = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        String jsReturnedValue = "";

        try {
            jsReturnedValue = String.valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(javascriptString));
            return (jsReturnedValue.equals(targetString));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.info("Looking for: " + javascriptString + ", e.message: " + e.getMessage());
          return true;  // If Javascript not found then don't wait for it
        }
      }
    }; // Terminates statement started by ExpectedCondition<Boolean> isLoaded = ...

  return wait.until(isLoaded);
}
```

And just to round it out, Ajax

```
public boolean waitForPrototypeAjax(WebDriver driver, int timeout) {
    return waitFor(driver, "return Ajax.activeRequestCount;", "0", timeout);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, as I know the application is using jquery not AngularJs. So i used your first example. And it didnt work. Have you opened the link which I attached? When you willl click on of the radionbuttons u will see the form. I've changed `Wait<WebDriver> wait_element = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 40);` to `Wait<WebDriver> wait_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40)`; because it was marked (webDriver cannot be resolved to a variable)

Comment: Can you be more specific about "didn't work"?  Also, please post the updated code that you executed. Please note that [Marionette and geckodriver are not yet feature complete. This means it does not yet offer full conformance with the WebDriver standard or complete compatibility with Selenium.](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver). So I use selenium-java v2.53.1 and firefox v47.0.

Comment: I've switched to chrome webdriver and selenium-java v2.53 and that solved my problems. Thank you Mike.